# FirstViewController как DataSource для SecondViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

Добрый день. Создал проект TabledViewApplication. По умолчанию создается FirstViewController  и SecondViewController. Я решил что в первом контроллере будет производиться вычисление и при нажатии кнопки добавляться результат в массив. Во втором контроллере добавил TableView. Задал идентификатор для ячейки, в которой будут отображаться данные из массива. Возникли два вопроса. Как указать второму контроллеру что данные для ячейки ему поставляет первый? 
Если заработает, то как отобразить данные из массива если они в Double (cell.textlabel?.text ругается что данные не типа String), так правильно  `cell.textLabel?.text = String (arrayTime[indexPath.row])`?

PS В первый контроллер добавил протоколы UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate и методы для них. Во втором контроллере никакой код не писал.

[FirstViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlGcs.png)

[image: Ошибки в классе для лейбла ячейки]

Comment: передать данные надо один раз при создании второго контроллера или постоянно перегонять по мере обновления? Касательно double в string: `cell.textLabel?.text = String(format:"%f", arrayTime[indexPath.row])`

Comment: всмысле перегонять? Весь результат сохраняется в массив (иного способа хранения пока не освоил).  Данные из массива отображаются в ячейке. Данные это количество часов и количество денег.

Comment: эти данные меняются в процессе работы программы или их надо передать один раз и все?

Comment: каждый раз добавляя результат в массив, создается новая ячейка. Старая ячейка тоже остается. Я пока ждал ответа посмотрел туториал, но там всего один контроллер+TableView. Для лэйблов ячейки создан отдельный класс. У меня же два контроллера соединены(простите, не знаю как описать) через Tab Bar Controller.  Я также как и там добавил TableView, одну ячейку. Создал лейбл в ячейке. Для него класс и добавил туда этот лейбл. Как бы все должно работать, но не хочет. Дело уже даже не в DataSource. Появились другие ошибки.

Comment: добавил скриншоты ошибок.

Comment: переделал название лейбла и все заработало. Теперь осталось как-то заставить ячейку видеть откуда брать информацию.

Comment: Может ли бы причиной проблемы то что связывает их TabBarController?

Comment: идея примерно такая. у вас есть два контроллера. если один из них создает другой то либо передайте в ините, либо, если надо передавать несколько раз, то дайте одному референс на второй и читайте напрямую. если они меду собой не связаны, то опять же либо передайте референс через какой то посредник, либо нормально вынесите всю логику в модель и пусть оба читают/пишут это модель.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36494/discussion-between-metman-and-max-mikheyenko).

Comment: что то у вас в чате ничего нет

Comment: Извините. Случайно нажал на чат. Я переделал проект, добавил CoreData. Реализовываю сохранение данных.

Comment: у вам там такие сложные данные, что прям coredata понадобилась?

Comment: Нет. Я же учусь. Тем более приложение для себя делаю.